# Postgres JSONB column insert error: invalid input syntax for type json the input string ended unexpectedly

Tags: json, dbeaver

I'm trying to create a row manually via DBeaver and I am entering the following in a jsonb column:

```
{"US":"0.880","PA":"0.028","KY":"0.025"}
```

I've checked that this is valid JSON on https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#

However, this is what I get:

[image]

Any insight would be appreciated...

I even tried surrounding the object with single quotes like:

```
'{"US":"0.880","PA":"0.028","KY":"0.025"}'
```

But got an error about how the ' is an invalid token...

I was writing a nodejs script to insert a json stringified object into the column but I was getting the same error so I decided to manually try it and I can't even insert the above data...

Comment: Please add details to question, this works nicely on Postgres: `select '{"US":"0.880","PA":"0.028","KY":"0.025"}'::jsonb;`.   (Using `PostgreSQL 12.6 (Ubuntu 12.6-0ubuntu0.20.10.1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 10.2.0-13ubuntu1) 10.2.0, 64-bit`).

Comment: I'm adding the object manually via DBEAVER (DBMS) to the column... shouldn't it work?

Comment: Check the servers log file to see what it was sent.

Comment: Agree with @jjanes: This may be more an issue with DBEAVER than with PostgreSQL itself.

Answer (score 2):

I can insert this data in jsonb column in DBeaver via UI without problem.

But we have issue about input in json(not jsonb) column in table which has no primary key. Maybe is this your case https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/11704 ?

Or can you show table DDL?

[insertjsonb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtODU.png)

Comment: Hey, thanks for checking. I basically moved on. I still don't know why it wasn't working. It works if I insert it using an SQL query though. What I was doing is using the 'create column' functionality in the 'view table data' section